# Saving a string to a .setting variable

Tags: c#, settings.settings

I'm trying to save a string variable from my FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath().

Using a breakpoint I can see that the string is correctly loaded onto SelectedPath(), but I can't save that string to the .settings file for the life of me. Any help?

```
    public void LocateWoWFolder()
    {
        using (FolderBrowserDialog FileDialogWindow = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            if (FileDialogWindow.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Using a breakpoint here I can see that nothing is loaded to .WoWFolderLocation.
                Properties.Settings.Default.WoWFolderLocation = FileDialogWindow.SelectedPath.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

The setting WoWFolderLocation is string type, and is a User scope setting. What am I doing wrong? :P

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282748/my-app-config-file-isnt-saving-anything-i-modify/1282833#1282833.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`.

:)

Answer (score 2):

You must call ...

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Check out [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx).